# therubyracer error on heroku as "Failed to install gems via Bundler."

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, therubyracer

When i push my app to heroku it gives me following error

```
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * therubyracer
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
```

I deleted my Gemlock file and again bundle install it but still gives me same error. I also tried  `bundle install --without development:test` for production it also gives me same error What can I do. Here is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'

#gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS

#gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
#gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'mysql2'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.2', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'devise'
gem 'hirb'

# Gems used for Facebook
gem 'facebook_oauth'
gem 'oauth','0.4.7'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem 'thin'
gem 'pg'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  #gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try run `bundle install` than push changes to remote repo.

Also if you use therubyracer for assets compilation, you may precompile assets locally and read this docs:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#therubyracer

Answer (score 0):

`therubyracer` gem is used to evaluate `JavaScript` from within `Ruby`(It embeds the JavaScript interpreter into Ruby).

This gem is required, if you are developing in Ubuntu since, ubuntu doesn't have a `Javascript runtime`.

But its not case with `Heroku`.

So, just keep the line for `therubyracer` gem in the `Gemfile` under `development` group like shown below :

```
group :development do
  gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.2', :platforms => :ruby
end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#therubyracer):

> If you were previously using therubyracer or therubyracer-heroku, these gems are no longer required and **strongly discouraged** as these gems use a very large amount of memory.

As a replacement on Ubuntu you can install NodeJS:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```