# application.js does not compile or load coffeescript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, aptana

application.js does not load any script file into it. The code is shown below. I try it hours but I have no clue how to solve this problem. Anyone helps?

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require datepicker
//= require_tree .
;
```

and my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~>3.1.0'
gem 'thor','>=0.14.4'
gem 'nifty-generators'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
gem 'rbbcode'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
  gem 'sprockets', '~>2.0.0'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Somehow, it does not load anything. I try to precompile them, but it shows an error

```
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeError:
(in c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.min.js)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I try couple solution such as downgrade my ruby from 2.0.0 to 1.9.3 but it does not work. Also rails version is 3.1.0

whole --trace precompile

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to s
kip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
```

......
    C:\Users\WebDev\AppData\Local\Temp\execjs20140806-8216-16s9hrzjs(487, 5) (null): Incorrect function.

```
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeError:
  (in c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.min.js)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the stack trace ?

Comment: it shows the same thing. No difference.

Comment: Which javascript runtime are you using? Have you tried NodeJS? Maybe reinstalling your javascript runner changes something...

Comment: I'm sure that the project run well on other machine, except my machine. I use Aptana Studio. I'm not sure what js runtime I use. I will try NodeJS

Comment: Has it worked on other windows machines?

Comment: yes, It works without any error

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are trying it in production mode. Please replace `gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby` with the below code in Gemfile,

```
group :development do
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
end
```

and run `bundle install`.

Also, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16784942/1896986

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

So I'm assuming the `application.js` file you're talking about is the concatinated and minified version of all your coffeescript (and javascript for that matter) assets, correct? If that's the case, I'd suggest running the following command:

`rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`.

If you still get errors, I'd bet it's a problem with the javascript runtime - in which case the solution suggested by @Rajesh seems like a good solution.